# Executing PowerShell script with Add-PnPFolder failed but works on command prompt

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

I created a simple script to create a Sharepoint2013 folder.
If I execute each line one by one on the PowerShell command prompt the folder is created.

If I try to run the script in PowerShell ISE run as Administrator I get the error

> Get-PnpFolder: File Not Found.

The content script is:

```
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$FolderRelativeURL,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$FolderToCreate
)


Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2013

Get-Command -Name Connect-PnPOnline

$SiteURL = "https://myOrg.org/sites/MyLIB"

Connect-PnPOnline –Url $SiteUrl -UseWebLogin

Get-PnPFolder -RelativeURL $FolderRelativeURL

Add-PnPFolder -Folder $FolderRelativeURL -Name $FolderToCreate

Disconnect-PnPOnline
´´´
Any clues ?
```

Comment: Show us how you  call the script. My guess is that the parameter is not set, or not set correctly.

Comment: I press the run button on PowerShell, it requests the both variables.

Supply values for the following parameters:
FolderRelativeURL: "/rfl/00. RCMs POC"
FolderToCreate: Test

Comment: Maybe add a `write-host $FolderRelativeURL` to validate the correct value is used in both cases? This is not really something we can answer here, you will have to debug this on your machine and slowly narrow down the problem.

Comment: Has I wrote before, if I follow the same steps on command prompt it works, with same variable contents. 
I see the folder created in Sharepoint.
When I ran the script I get an error on Get-PnPFolder or Add-PnPFolder, and the error is File Not Found for both.

My question is why it's not the case on command prompt ?

Comment: Again, the best we could do here is vague guesses, not knowing anything about your environment. I've had similar issues like this before. All you can do is systematic trouble shooting to see where the difference between both cases is. Narrow down the issue. Maybe try using a hardcoded string for example, and see if the issue remains. You need to eliminate one factor after the other to narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: I follow your suggestion,
when I initialize the variables into the script it runs.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: I suppose, the problem is about how you enter the values then. Maybe it's a copy-paste problem, or there's some stray characters, or host encoding, etc .. That's why I said add  a "write-host" or anything else to test if it's actually the correct value. Alternatively, specify the parameters explictly when calling the script.

Answer (score 0):

@marsze point me the solution, it's a copy paste situation.

The first parameter I past (in bold), **"/rfl/00. RCMs POC"**

The correct input (in bold), **/rfl/00.%20RCMs%20POC**

Thanks @marsze